# Add support opening file through windows command parameters (file path as parameter)

Tags: c#

I have a tools only support opening "*.TMC" file by dragging - or use its "open" button I am going to make this tools support opening file through windows command parameters (file path as parameter) such as

start "" "TMC Polygon Tool.exe" "e:\tmcfile\kasumi.tmc"

Here is the link to the source file http://www.mediafire.com/download/mc72m97h876i550/TMC.zip

Here is a part of "App.g.i.cs" (this is the original code,which works but not accept open through command parameters)

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public static void Main() {
    TMC_Tool.App app = new TMC_Tool.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

and a part of "MainWindow.xaml.cs"

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) => this.DragMove();
    MainWindowTitle();
    changeLanguage();
    MessageWindow.lang(txt);
    ObjectSelectWindow.lang(txt);
    objSelWindow = new ObjectSelectWindow();
    Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;    
}
```

i tried to add string[] args , to use the existing method "OpenFile(args[0])" ,but it cause error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Here is my code (which causes the error) "App.g.i.cs"

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TMC_Tool.App app = new TMC_Tool.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run(new MainWindow(args));
}
```

"MainWindow.xaml.cs"

```
public MainWindow(string[] args)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (args.Length > 0)
    {
        String FileEx = Path.GetExtension(args[0]).ToUpper();
        if (FileEx == ".TMC")
        OpenFile(args[0]);
    }
    this.MouseLeftButtonDown += (sender, e) => this.DragMove();

    MainWindowTitle();
    changeLanguage();
    MessageWindow.lang(txt);
    ObjectSelectWindow.lang(txt);
    objSelWindow = new ObjectSelectWindow();

    Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;
}
```

Edit :
It works now ,
the *Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()* is really helpful

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public static void Main()
        {
            TMC_Tool.App app = new TMC_Tool.App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }


public string filePath = null;
public MainWindow()
{
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
// original code  .... 
filePath = args.Length > 1 ? args[1] : null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            OpenFile(filePath);
        }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the Value of Environment.CommandLine in Main() method? Form the project menu, you can add command line parameters for debugging, this will help you debug the application with the command line parameters specified. Or you can put a Debugger.Break() as the first line of Main() method to attach your debugger during runtime

Comment: Thank you ,i am try doing it :)

Comment: hi again, i try saving the path in "strFilePath" variable of MainWIndow. Then i use the Loaded event and call OpenFile using the saved path if it is not null. but it cause an error i" Member 'string.IsNullOrEmpty(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead "

Comment: it seems that i can't insert code in the comment ,so i added it to the bottom of the first post ,if you don't mind please help ,Thanks so much

Comment: You should get that command argument first. We have to make sure args is not null. Then args[0] is not null and is the path to the file. Just debug your app please.

Comment: I edited your post for the string error

Comment: Thank you very much ,it works, i added the working code in the first post

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks to @tlj also.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your original code.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    // path will be in args[1] if there is any.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,it works, i added the working code in the first post